# Is there a way to get the row number in Mysql like the rownum in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Is there a way to get the row number in Mysql like the rownum in oracle, If not then is there any indirect way of doing it?
please suggest.

Comment: There is no rank functionality. Refer this [Stackoverflow question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Until MySQL finally supports [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides), the only way to get something similar is this:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
   < your original query goes here >
) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Answer (score -6):

The best practice is to add an **auto incrementing ID** for each row. This would also help you a lot if, one day, you choose to use relational tables.

In phpMyAdmin, when you create (or edit) a table, you'll see the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option. You can only have one column with auto IDs enabled.

Edit: This is how you database would look like:

```
id | name  | email | phone
1    Tekin   ...     ...
2    John    ...     ...
3    Jane    ...     ...
```

Comment: That is something completely different to a `row_number()` value. What if you want to get the row number after sorting by a specific column?