# Switched from Oracle Db to MySQL. Named query no longer works

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This works with Oracle, but we have been told to switch to MySQL.  After changing the driver info and other pertinent settings to point to a MySQL DB, I am no longer able to execute my named queries.  Here is the simplest one as defined in the Entity:

> @NamedQuery(name="get_capability", query="select cb from Capability cb where cb.financial_Id = :fiId")

Then I have code to execute the query as follows:

> query = em.createNamedQuery("get_capability");
>
> .
>   .
>   .
>
> query.setParameter("fiId", fiId);
>
> query.setMaxResults(1);
>
> cabability = (Capability) query.getSingleResult();

This last line throws an exception:

> 2013-04-24 10:46:00,677 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 1248, SQLState: 42000
>
> 2013-04-24 10:46:00,677 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Every derived table must have its own alias

The SQL that gets generated is logged in the log file as follows:

```
/* named HQL query get_capability */ select
    * 
from
    ( select
        capability0_.FINANCIAL_ID as FINANCIAL1_272_,
        capability0_.ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS as ACTIVE2_272_,
        capability0_.ALLOWED_CONNECTIONS as ALLOWED3_272_,
        capability0_.COMPLETE_DETAILS as COMPLETE4_272_,
        capability0_.FI_NAME as FI5_272_,
        capability0_.MESSAGE_FORMAT as MESSAGE6_272_,
        capability0_.PROVIDER_ID as PROVIDER7_272_,
        capability0_.STATUS as STATUS272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_ACCOUNTS as SUPPORTS9_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_CUSTOMER as SUPPORTS10_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_IMAGE as SUPPORTS11_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_STATEMENTS as SUPPORTS12_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS as SUPPORTS13_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_TRANSFER as SUPPORTS14_272_ 
    from
        INSTITUTION capability0_ 
    where
        capability0_.FINANCIAL_ID=? ) 
where
    rownum <= ?
```

I've read what this error means, that there needs to be an alias for every derived table, and I can edit the derived SQL to get it to work by adding an alias.  My question is this.  Since this is a derived query (SQL), how do I tell hibernate to add an alias, or tell MySQL to not require it?

Hibernate partial config:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />   
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
<property name="hibernate.showSql" value="true" /> 
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Did you change the dialect in Hibernate config?

Comment: I believe so.  I changed the entry in persistence.xml.  The pertinent entries now look like this:    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.showSql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
   <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>

Comment: Problem solved.  It turns out I had the hibernate dialect defined in two places.  Once was still set for Oracle.  After I changed that, it started to work.  Thanks to all who helped out.

Comment: I've added the previous comment as an answer, feel free to add information that might be useful for other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ROWNUM` is a Oracle keyword that is not supported in MySQL (for example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8509996/422353)) I think Hibernate is still targetting Oracle when it builds the queries.

Verify that you've changed to the corresponding Hibernate dialect.

*(Answer added for posterity)*

Answer (score 0):

your subquery in the FROM is the "derived table", you have to name that derived table.

Something like this should work

```
select
    RES.field1, RES.field2 
from
    ( select
        capability0_.FINANCIAL_ID as FINANCIAL1_272_,
        capability0_.ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS as ACTIVE2_272_,
        capability0_.ALLOWED_CONNECTIONS as ALLOWED3_272_,
        capability0_.COMPLETE_DETAILS as COMPLETE4_272_,
        capability0_.FI_NAME as FI5_272_,
        capability0_.MESSAGE_FORMAT as MESSAGE6_272_,
        capability0_.PROVIDER_ID as PROVIDER7_272_,
        capability0_.STATUS as STATUS272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_ACCOUNTS as SUPPORTS9_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_CUSTOMER as SUPPORTS10_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_IMAGE as SUPPORTS11_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_STATEMENTS as SUPPORTS12_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS as SUPPORTS13_272_,
        capability0_.SUPPORTS_TRANSFER as SUPPORTS14_272_ 
    from
        INSTITUTION capability0_ 
    where
        capability0_.FINANCIAL_ID=? ) **RES**
where
    rownum <= ?
```