# Get row number (like excel)

Tags: mysql

How would I get the row number of a mysql output, for example:

```
select * from table

name      age
David     12
Frank     13
```

I want to get the row number, like so:

```
select *, row_num from table

row    name      age
1      David     12
2      Frank     13
```

[image]

The row number on the left -- 1 through 7 -- not a part of the data itself.

Comment: Typically there's a primary key value used for that. Should we assume no id/pk field?

Comment: @Dan yes, no primary key, I just want it to return the row number of the result.

Comment: @Dan does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509996/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-row-number-in-mysql-like-the-rownum-in-oracle do what you want?

Comment: @Bryce I think you meant to ask the OP, not me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql, you have to use [`User-Defined Variables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

```
SELECT @rowno := @rowno + 1 AS row_no, *
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rowno := 0) t
-- ORDER BY age
```