# MySQL - Query for all rows except first one

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on the getting a result of a query like-

I need all the rows from a table except the first rows, cause i have another query for the first one only.

```
SELECT * FROM `about_news` WHERE `type` = 'latest' ORDER BY `news_id` DESC LIMIT 1, ?
```

What to put in the place `?` sign to get all the results?? I think starting from 1 is correct.

Comment: Just specify a number largest enough to return all records.

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509996/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-row-number-in-mysql-like-the-rownum-in-oracle

Comment: Alternatively if `news_id` is your PK, you can use a sub-query: `SELECT * FROM about_news WHERE type = 'latest' AND news_id NOT IN (SELECT news_id FROM about_news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY news_id DESC`

Comment: Yes it works for me. Thanks to everyone, I already search for the answer but didn't find... May be it is because of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have query for first row, than it means you already have it's ID.

```
SELECT * FROM `about_news` WHERE `id` != :firstRowId AND `type` = 'latest' ORDER BY `news_id`
```

and pass in first row ID.

Comment: This is also works fine.