# How to optimize limit query to access data faster from a huge table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, datatable

I am trying to fetch data from a table of size 9 GB + and having millions of records. I'm populating DataTable with that data. I am getting the records in chunks from the table i.e 10 per page through Ajax and SQL Limit query.

[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sTpF.png)

In the above image you can see We have `223,740` pages so when i try to access the last page the query takes forever to load the data. However data loads quicker when i try to access first pages. But accessing higher offset pages directly takes forever to load.

```
 public static function getAllEvaluationsWithNameForDataTable($start){
        $queryBuilder = new Builder();

        return  $queryBuilder
            ->from(array('e' =>  static::class))
            ->leftJoin('Cx\Framework\Models\Common\User\CxUser',  'e.cx_hc_user_id = u.id', 'u')
            ->columns('e.id, e.first_name, u.initials as assigned_coach, e.gender, e.email, e.phone, e.age, e.version, e.evaluation_status, e.ip_address, e.date_created, e.date_updated')
            ->orderBy('e.id asc')
            ->limit(10, $start)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
            ->toArray();
}
```

PHP Function/Controller:

```
public function getEvaluationsAction() {
        // Enable Json response
        $this->setJsonResponse();
        // This action can be called only via ajax
        $this->requireAjax();

        // Forward to access denied if current user is not allowed to view evaluation details
        if (!$this->CxAuth->currentUserIsAllowedTo('VIEW', CxEbEvaluation::getClassResourceName()))
            return $this->forwardToAccessDeniedError();

        if(isset($_GET['start'])){
            $start = $this->request->get('start');
        }else{
            $start = 10;
        }

        $recordsTotal = count(CxEbEvaluation::getAllForDataTable(array('id')));

        //Get Evaluations from DB
        $evaluation_quizzes = CxEbEvaluation::getAllEvaluationsWithNameForDataTable(intval($start));

        //for getting base URL
        $url = new Url();

        $data = array();

        foreach ($evaluation_quizzes as $key => $quiz) {
            $data[ $key ][ 'id' ] = $quiz[ 'id' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'first_name' ] = $quiz[ 'first_name' ];
            if($quiz[ 'assigned_coach' ]){
                $data[ $key ][ 'assigned_coach' ] = $quiz['assigned_coach'];
            }else{
                $data[ $key ][ 'assigned_coach' ] = "Not assigned";
            }

            $data[ $key ][ 'gender' ] = $quiz[ 'gender' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'email' ] = $quiz[ 'email' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'phone' ] = $quiz[ 'phone' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'age' ] = $quiz[ 'age' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'version' ] = $quiz[ 'version' ];
            $data[ $key ][ 'quiz' ] =  $url->get('/admin/get-evaluation-quiz-by-id');
            $data[ $key ][ 'manage-notes-messages-and-calls' ] =  $url->get('/admin/manage-notes-messages-and-calls');
            $data[ $key ][ 'date_created' ] = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", $quiz[ 'date_created' ]);
            $data[ $key ][ 'evaluation_status' ] = $quiz[ 'evaluation_status' ];
        }
        // Return data array
        return array(
            "recordsTotal"    => $recordsTotal,
            "recordsFiltered" => $recordsTotal ,
            "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
        );
        // Return data
    }
```

Javascript:

```
cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbEvaluation = $CxRecordsTable.cxAdminDataTable({
        ajaxUrl: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-evaluations')?>' + eqQuizIdQueryString,
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        recordsFiltered :true,
        columns: [
            cx.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id',{ delete: true }),
            { data: 'first_name' },
            { data: 'assigned_coach' },
            { data: 'gender' },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'phone' },
            { data: 'age' },
            cx.common.admin.tableLinkColumn('quiz', quizLinkOptions),
            cx.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id', healthCoachLinkOptions),
            cx.common.admin.tableLinkColumn('manage-notes-messages-and-calls', manageNotesMessagesAndCalls),
            { data: 'date_created' },
            cx.common.admin.tableSwitchableColumn('evaluation_status', {
                editable: true,
                createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).data('evaluation-status-id', rowData.id);
                },
                onText: 'Complete',
                offText: 'In progress'
            })
        ],
        toolbarOptions:{
            enabled: false
        },          success: function (data) {
                            cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbEvaluation.cxAdminDataTable("reloadAjax");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $row.removeClass('alert');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I hope the question is clear. If anything else is required just update me I will provide.

(From Comment)

```
SELECT  e.id` AS id, e.first_name AS first_name,
        u.initials AS assigned_coach,
        e.gender AS gender, e.email AS email, e.phone AS phone,
        e.age AS age, e.version AS version,
        e.evaluation_status AS evaluation_status,
        e.ip_address AS ip_address, e.date_created AS date_created,
        e.date_updated AS date_updated
    FROM  evaluation_client AS e
    LEFT JOIN  cx_user AS u  ON e.cx_hc_user_id = u.id
    ORDER BY  e.id ASC
    LIMIT  :APL0 OFFSET, :APL1
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66294/optimize-a-query-on-two-big-tables

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75963/optimizing-large-database-query-25-million-rows-using-max-and-group-by

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down

Comment: you need an index.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile tried the above stackoverflow link but it isn't related to my scenario.

Comment: @Hogan can you point out in my query? I already have id PK?

Comment: Run an explain on yoru query and you can have the system point it out for you.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile What do you think of applying the sub-query logic with `@rownum` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510069/2191572 and using `WHERE` on the outer query's `row_number` to simulate a `LIMIT`?

Comment: @Hogan `Array
(
    [sql] => SELECT `e`.`id` AS `id`, `e`.`first_name` AS `first_name`, `u`.`initials` AS `assigned_coach`, `e`.`gender` AS `gender`, `e`.`email` AS `email`, `e`.`phone` AS `phone`, `e`.`age` AS `age`, `e`.`version` AS `version`, `e`.`evaluation_status` AS `evaluation_status`, `e`.`ip_address` AS `ip_address`, `e`.`date_created` AS `date_created`, `e`.`date_updated` AS `date_updated` FROM `evaluation_client` AS `e`  LEFT JOIN `cx_user` AS `u` ON `e`.`cx_hc_user_id` = `u`.`id` ORDER BY `e`.`id` ASC LIMIT :APL0 OFFSET :APL1
`

Comment: Here is a good article explaining all necessary concepts. It is based on Postgres, but the concepts apply to all databases. [Pagination Done the Right Way](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way). As the domain name suggests, the primary theme is "use the index".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to dates column datatype in my table. I was using `int` datatype for dates fields and when I changed the datatype of my dates column to `datetime`, the search results were in seconds.

Source where i found the solution @ http://dbscience.blogspot.com/2008/08/can-timestamp-be-slower-than-datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

The [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down) question and answers, linked by Masivuye Cokile, as well as https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/ link provided there, contain an excellent rundown on why large offset queries are slow.  Basically, for `LIMIT 150000, 10` MySQL still scans the entire 150000 rows even if it discards them later. To speed it up you can either:

- use sequential pagination, i.e. "show 10 entries after ID #N", which works very fast and is a good alternative, but discards actual page number; your users will be left with "next/prev" links and/or an approximate page number you can calculate using a `count` query.
- or create an index on `id`, then force mysql to perform an index-only search.

For the second approach, you'll have to rewrite the query from

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM table t 
WHERE ...
ORDER by t.id ASC
LIMIT 150000, 10
```

to

```
SELECT  ...
  FROM (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table
        ORDER BY
                id ASC
        LIMIT 150000, 10
        ) o
JOIN table t
  ON t.id = o.id
WHERE ...
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

Alternatively, since you're not confined to the single query, you can retrieve the ID of the first item on your page using

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table 
 ORDER BY id ASC 
 LIMIT 150000, 1
```

then use said id to retrieve actual data:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table
 WHERE id >= $id
   AND ...
 ORDER BY id ASC
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: [_More_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) on 'remembering where you left off'.

Comment: @Timekiller where to find the id of first item? Do you mean $start variable of datatable?

Comment: First item overall or first item on page? If you mean overall, either `select min(id)` or use something like `id >= 0`; if you mean first item on page, look at my second to last query and adjust the `limit 150000, 1` part so that offset matches `pages*items_per_page` instead of 150000.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `SELECT whatever FROM vast_table ORDER BY something LIMIT 10 large_number` is a notorious performance antipattern.  Why? Because it has to examine a great many rows just to return a few.

If your `id` value is a primary key (or any indexed column) you can paginate by

```
SELECT whatever FROM vast_table WHERE id BETWEEN large_value AND large_value+9 ORDER BY id;
```

Or you might try

```
SELECT whatever FROM vast_table WHERE id >= large_value ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
```

This doesn't paginate perfectly if your `id` values have gaps in them. But it performs tolerably well.

Comment: Hello @O. Jones i already tried similar but as you mentioned it skips records.

`return  $queryBuilder
            ->from(array('e' =>  static::class))
            ->leftJoin('Cx\Framework\Models\Common\User\CxUser',  'e.cx_hc_user_id = u.id', 'u')
            ->columns('e.*')
            ->where('e.id > :ID:')
            ->orderBy('e.id asc')
            ->limit(10, $start)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute(array('ID' => $start))
            ->toArray();`

Comment: @DojoDev - Well, sounds like QueryBuilder is not a good tool for this use.

Comment: You shouldn't include your starting point in `limit(10, $start) `. And you probably want `where('e.id >=  :ID:')` note `>=`.