# Select Row Number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the rownumber of each row from a MySQL Table. I already read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509996/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-row-number-in-mysql-like-the-rownum-in-oracle) and tried the suggested select statement as below,

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
   select * from myTable
) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

But I am getting in syntax error as below when I ran in `Dbeaver`,

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
   select * from myTable
) t,
(SELECT @r' at line 1
```

Can someone please help? I am new to MySQL. I am using version `8.0`. Once it's tested I would basically want to use this select in my `Apache Spark Code`

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is a reserved word, do you don't have mysql 8 ?

Comment: Can you please help me with it? I want to select the entire row along with row number? select ROW_NUMBER(),* from myTable. It doesn't work.

Comment: which mysql version  are you using, depending on your answer, the answer will difeer, besides that, an row_number needs an order by

Comment: Thanks @nbk. I misunderstood when you said reserved word. I tried solution by Divya Prakash and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

use this one:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_num, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
   select * from myTable
) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r;
```

`row_number` is a reserved keyword of mysql, you can not use it as alias or for any other purpose.

Comment: Thanks much! It worked. Not sure why the other post has this as accepted solution

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran since your version of MySql is 8.0 you should not use variables to get row numbers. Take some time to read about ROW_NUMBER() window function and use it.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Let me check it. I was in a hurry. Will spend some time

Comment: this will work even in mysql 8 (the error you got is just because "row_number" is now a reserved word), but as of mysql 8 setting variables in a select is officially deprecated; you can expect it to stop working in some future version.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
 SELECT *,   
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 'some column' ) AS row_num  
    FROM my_table
```

(https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-row_number-function)

Comment: we still don't know which mysql version he has

Comment: He says he is using version 8.0

Comment: I want to select the entire row along with row number. I don't want it to be partitioned on some column. Or then in my case it has be over partitioned on all the columns in the tables. There is a rownum, * in oracle that gets the rownum along with each record in table. Isn't there anything similar or easier to use?

Comment: You don't need the partition by, but you should specify an order by in the over clause

Comment: Can you please share an example query? I don't have any PK in my table. I have 100000 rows in my table. What i need is rownum column from 1,2,.. 100000 along with all the other columns.

Comment: then just `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as row_num`.  but be aware that sql data does *not* have any innate order; there's no guarantee the row number you get will have any reproducable order beyond the one query.

Comment: @ysth - I tried this. SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by column  ) AS row_num
    FROM myTable. myTable has 120M records. The query seems to run forever. Is there a better way?

Comment: how long does it take with just `select *`?  adding `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` shouldn't make it take longer (with no order by).  but then the row number is just something you could set in your client anyway.  maybe take a step back and edit your question to say *why* you want a row number, what you intend to use it for?  maybe even consider adding a PK to your table (mysql will be creating a hidden one for you anyway, at least with innodb)